# Why is the option to download a livestreamed video greyed out?

Tags: youtube

I have created a few livestreams via YouTube and notice that the option to download them is greyed out.

Some details:

- videos are private (which I didn't think would restrict me personally)
- recorded less than 24 hours ago (some forums have mentioned this)
- accessed through YouTube Studio

I go to the video in question through YouTube Studio, select the three-dot menu, and that is where I see the greyed out "Download" option.

Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: I did 6 live streams since yesterday. The 3 that were each less than 18 mins in duration all worked fine. They have thumbnails, and their Download button works. The other 3 are 49m07s to 1h38m29s and don't have thumbnails, and their Download buttons are grayed out and disabled. I'm trying to figure out how to fix them and how to prevent these problems from happening.

Answer (score 2):

For me and others seems like there's a "processing time". Usually I have to wait around 15-20 hours to be able to download a livestream.